# Is there another word except of "of" in which its letter "f" pronounced as "v"?

Tags: pronunciation

I have learned that the word "of" is pronounced as "ov". 
Are there any other words in which the letter "f" is pronounced as "v", or it is **one** exception?

Comment: "Roofs" is sometimes pronounced with /v/, although the singular has /f/.  With most similar words, the "v" spelling is used for the plural ("halves", "calves", usually "hooves").

Comment: Others are "hereof", "thereof", "whereof".

Comment: Some of the things that were mentioned here, were also mentioned in the Concise Oxford Companion to the English Language. Here is the text is here hoping it will help to other people which are seeking the same question. 
http://www.encyclopedia.com/literature-and-arts/language-linguistics-and-literary-terms/language-and-linguistics/f

Comment: There are surely several obscure words too, such as [afanc](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/afanc).

Comment: Very good word, Laurel. Bravo!

Comment: Rjpond, all of those words have "of" in them; they're just ligated. But I like it!

Comment: I bet dollars to donuts that this is a historical change that only happened with "of" and its derivatives, since these are among the only words in English with with an "of" (not "off") as a final. I'm taking a guess here, but "of" was probably originally said similar to /ɑf/ and "off" to /ɑff/. Then when geminate (i.e. double) consonants disappeared from English, final /f/ went to /v/ and final /ff/ went to /f/. In short, "of" and its derivatives use "v" because "of" and "off" were pronounced differently long ago anyway.

Comment: Close: “ph”, which is normally pronounced as /f/, is instead pronounced as /v/ when it occurs *in my name*.

Answer (score 1):

rjpond is right -- I was going to say "no" but I see that s/he answered it in the comments instead of as an answer, so I'll repeat the answer here:  "hereof," "whereof," and "thereof" are pronounced with a "v."

Answer (score 1):

In the Welsh language, the letter “f” is always pronounced like the English “v”, and so Welsh place names (e.g. Caernarfon) and personal names (e.g. Ifor) should have the “f” pronounced as “v” even when used by English speakers.

Comment: As far as I know, in Welsh, *f* is pronounced /v/ and *ff* is pronounced /f/. [Faint](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faint#Welsh) is /vai̯nt/.

Comment: @Wistful Yes, quite right, I should have said that a single “f” is pronounced as a “v”.