# Word(s) in which 'V' is pronounced /f/

Tags: word-request, pronunciation

I was reading [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148018/is-there-another-word-except-of-of-in-which-its-letter-f-pronounced-as-v) and it reminded me of a word (I've forgotten now) which was the opposite of that question i.e. a word in which the letter V is pronounced /f/. I racked my brain for about an hour but to no avail. I can't come up with it and there are thousands of words that have V, so Googling didn't help either.

As far as I remember, the V in this word is in an unstressed syllable (it also has a variant pronunciation with /v/).

Does anyone know the word I'm talking about?

Comment: *Have*, here in the midwestern U.S., is very frequently pronounced *haff*.  It is very often combined with the word *to* and the pair of words are then pronounced *hafta*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Leitmotiv* (sometimes spelt *leitmotif*) is pronounced /f/.  Other German borrowings such as *Vaterland* (nearly always) and *verboten* often have /f/.

*Mazel tov* is sometimes pronounced with /f/, but not always.

*Kalashnikov* (from Russian) is usually pronounced with /f/.

*Have to* is often /hæftu:/.

Comment: And sometimes Volkswagen too but I think the [v] version is more popular.

Comment: Ah.. [*verklempt*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/verklempt) is what I was thinking of. I've just remembered it.